# Detect list of items within a string

Tags: r, string, list

I am able to extract the requisite table from Wikipeida (see below). For each country, the table shows several bordering countries. For each country, I would like to extract a list containing it's bordering countries. Unfortunately, I'm having a little trouble and could use some help.

**Current Outcome**

```
Country   Neighbors
Albania   Greece
```

**Desired Outcome**

Ideally, I would like the countries to appear as a list so that it is possible to access each neighbor for each country.

```
Country   Neighbors
Albania   Greece; Kosovo; North Macedonia; Montenegro
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

**The code (so far)**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
library(lubridate)

# This code extracts the table and converts it to a dataframe 

xml2::read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_and_territories_by_land_borders")

land_borders <- page %>%
        html_nodes(xpath="/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[5]/div[1]/table") %>%
        html_table(fill=TRUE)

land_borders = data.frame(land_borders)

# Get the unique countries
unique_countries = land_borders[,1]
```

This code below extracts ONE country for each row. I would like to extract ALL the countries in the 6th column and have it appear as a list.

```
test = list()
test <- str_extract(land_borders[,6], paste(unique_countries, collapse="|"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str_extract_all` to extract list of all the countries and you can collapse them in one string with `toString`.

```
sapply(stringr::str_extract_all(land_borders[,6], 
       paste(unique_countries, collapse="|")), toString)

#[1] ""
#[2] "Russia, Georgia"
#[3] "Iran, Pakistan, Tajikistan, Turkmenistan, Uzbekistan"
#[4] "Greece, North Macedonia, Montenegro"
#[5] "Libya, Mali, Mauritania, Morocco, Niger, Tunisia"
#...       
#...
```

Comment: Brilliant! That's perfect. Thanks heaps. Works perfectly